# Flexsearch export and import document index issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, full-text-search, flexsearch

I'm trying to build an index on using flexsearch and nodejs and store it on a local disk as it take quite a bit of time to build. The export seems to work, but when trying to import the file again with a new document index I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'import' of undefined
at Q.t.import (/opt/hermetic/hermetic/server/node_modules/flexsearch/dist/flexsearch.bundle.js:33:330)
at Object.retrieveIndex (/opt/hermetic/hermetic/server/build/search.js:86:25)
at Object.search (/opt/hermetic/hermetic/server/build/search.js:96:32)
at init (/opt/hermetic/hermetic/server/build/server.js:270:27)
```

I'm running nodejs version 14 and flexsearch version 0.7.21. Below is the code I am using:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import Flexsearch from 'flexsearch';

const createIndex = async () => { 
    const { Document } = Flexsearch;
    const index = new Document({
      document: {
        id: 'id',
        tag: 'tag',
        store: true,
        index: [
          'record:a',
          'record:b',
          'tag',
        ],
      },
    });

    index.add({ id: 0, tag: 'category1', record: { a: '1 aaa', b: '0 bbb' } });
    index.add({ id: 1, tag: 'category1', record: { a: '1 aaa', b: '1 bbb' } });
    index.add({ id: 2, tag: 'category2', record: { a: '2 aaa', b: '2 bbb' } });
    index.add({ id: 3, tag: 'category2', record: { a: '2 aaa', b: '3 bbb' } });
    console.log('search', index.search('aaa'));

    await index.export((key, data) => fs.writeFile(`./search_index/${key}`, data, err => !!err && console.log(err)));
    return true;
}

const retrieveIndex = async () => { 
    const { Document } = Flexsearch;
    const index = new Document({
      document: {
        id: 'id',
        tag: 'tag',
        store: true,
        index: [
          'record:a',
          'record:b',
          'tag',
        ],
      },
    });

    const keys = fs
      .readdirSync('./search_index', { withFileTypes: true }, err => !!err && console.log(err))
      .filter(item => !item.isDirectory())
      .map(item => item.name);

    for (let i = 0, key; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
      key = keys[i];
      const data = fs.readFileSync(`./search_index/${key}`, 'utf8');
      index.import(key, data);
    }
    return index;
}

await createIndex();
const index = await retrieveIndex();

console.log('cached search', index.search('aaa'));
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flexsearch#export--import) says its possible, but the example only shows using the Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to find a way to export the index properly too, originally trying to put everything into one file. [While it worked, I didn't really like the solution](https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch/discussions/270).

Which brought me to your SO question, I've checked your code and managed to find out why you get that error.

Basically the export is a sync operation, while you also (randomly) use async. In order to avoid the issue, you need to remove all async code and only use sync `node.fs` operations. For my solution, I also only once created the Document store, to then just fill it via retrieveIndex() rather than creating `new Document()` per function.

I also added a .json extension to guarantee that `node.fs` reads the file properly and for sanity purposes - afterall it's json stored.

So thanks for giving me the idea to store each `key` as file @Jamie Nicholls

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import { Document } from 'flexsearch'

const searchIndexPath = '/Users/user/Documents/linked/search-index/'

  let index = new Document({
    document: {
      id: 'date',
      index: ['content']
    },
    tokenize: 'forward'
  })


const createIndex = () => { 
  
  index.add({ date: "2021-11-01", content: 'asdf asdf asd asd asd asd' })
  index.add({ date: "2021-11-02", content: 'fobar 334kkk' })
  index.add({ date: "2021-11-04", content: 'fobar 234 sffgfd' })

  index.export(
    (key, data) => fs.writeFileSync(`${searchIndexPath}${key}.json`, data !== undefined ? data : '')
  )
}

createIndex()

const retrieveIndex = () => { 

  const keys = fs
    .readdirSync(searchIndexPath, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter(item => !item.isDirectory())
    .map(item => item.name.slice(0, -5))

  for (let i = 0, key; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
    key = keys[i]
    const data = fs.readFileSync(`${searchIndexPath}${key}.json`, 'utf8')
    index.import(key, data ?? null)
  }
}


const searchStuff = () => {
  retrieveIndex()  
  console.log('cached search', index.search('fo'))
}

searchStuff()
```

Comment: edit: the data sometimes is `undefined`, hence why I checked for it in the export as it would throw otherwise

Comment: I am using the same code for import and export...however the `content.store` is not getting imported... How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this further, the feature is not currently available for document type searches. [See this issue in github for more information](https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch/issues/249)